# Using sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture methods on julia

Tags: scikit-learn, julia

can you help me how i can use all functions of sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture on Julia ?

```
     using PyPlot
     using ScikitLearn 
     using PyCall
     @pyimport sklearn.mixture as mix
     data=readcsv("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/data.csv",header=false)
     a=mix.GaussianMixture(3)
     a.fit(data)
```

the error is: type PyObject has no field fit

Comment: Try with `a[:fit](data)`. See the last part of the [usage section](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#usage) to see an explanation of this syntax.

Comment: thx for your answer, it works